# Mudar cor da rota (estrada) do google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, google-maps

[image: mudar linha de marcação do google maps, mudar cor da rota no google maps api]

Alguem pode me ajudar como muda essa cor azul da estrada quando define uma rota.. 
já tenho o style tudo pronto só não sei a variável que se aplica a essa parte do mapa.. Obg

```
 /*Estilizando o mapa;
  Criando um array com os estilos*/
  var styles = [

  ];

 /*crio um objeto passando o array de estilos (styles) e definindo um nome para ele*/
  var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {
    name: "Mapa Style"
  });

  /*Aplicando as configurações do mapa*/
  map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
  map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Para alterar a cor, é necessário utilizar `google.maps.DirectionsRenderer`. Com ele você poderá definir algumas características da linha, por exemplo:

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

const directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: true,
    map: map, /* Objeto google.maps.Map */
    polylineOptions: {
        strokeColor: "#F00" /* Cor em hexadecimal ou nome da cor em inglês */
    }
});
```

Como você já deve ter o código que faz a rota, irei deixar apenas um exemplo baixo.

```
directionsService.route({
    origin: 'Endereço #1',
    destination: 'Endereço #2',
    travelMode: 'DRIVING',
}, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
    }
});
```